# constexpr and function body = delete: what's the purpose?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

According to the [[dcl.constexpr/3]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#3):

> The definition of a constexpr function shall satisfy the following requirements:
>   [...]
>   - its function-body shall be = delete, = default, or [...]

This means that the following class snippet is valid:

```
struct S {
    constexpr void f() = delete;
};
```

What's the purpose of having a deleted `constexpr` function?
What are the benefit of defining it `constexpr` if any?

I can't figure out any reason, but the fact that maybe it's easier to allow it than to forbid it in the standard.

Comment: `delete`ing any function is a simple way to disable a particular overload. I guess it should be applied for a `constexpr` family of functions as well.

Comment: `constexpr` for functions returning `void` is also *fun*.

Comment: @Jarod42 Touché. Used to create a mvce and that's fine for it, but it makes sense indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was based on [CWG 1199](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1199). Daniel Krügler wrote:

> it could be useful to allow this form in a case where a single piece of code is used in multiple configurations, in some of which the function is `constexpr` and others deleted; having to update all declarations of the function to remove the constexpr specifier is unnecessarily onerous.

Comment: Sooner or later you must teach me how to search through the issues. I've never managed to find out what I was looking for!! That said, I cannot figure out such a case. Can you provide a minimal example?

Comment: @skypjack Not sure, tbh.

Comment: Possible [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e29e6fb25d185488) ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the purpose is the same as with any `=delete`:

If you inherit from a class, but don't want the function to be available in subclasses.

E.g.:

```
class P{
    public:
    constexpr int foo(){return 42;}

};

class C : public P{
    public:
    constexpr int foo() = delete; //(*)
};

int main() {
    P p;
    cout << p.foo(); //ok

    C c;    
    cout << c.foo(); //Compiler error only if line (*) is present.
    return 0;
}
```

Even though i can't tell you right now where it is usefull - but i also can't see any reason right now why it should be forbidden.

Comment: The result is the same even though you remove `constexpr` from `C`.